# Why charts axis labels are displayed differently?

Tags: lightning, dashboard, charts

I have a dashboard with various reports shown as charts in lightning in two environments. One is my dev and another is a test environment. Now for some odd reason, the charts are displayed a little differently between the two environments even though the the settings look identical in classic.

The issue is that we have two variables on the Y-axis. In the one environment, the two variable are displayed as so:

[image]

The two scales are even height but different values and on opposite sides. 
This is not what I want. In the other environment is looks as so:

[image]

With both variables on one side, separated by a comma. In classic, the chart options are the same! One interesting thing is that for the chart that looks how i want (comma separated), i can click the edit button in lightning, but I cannot click that button for the other environment.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks